# Describing relative locations of material objects in Latin

Tags: syntax, translation-check, sentence-translation

I tried translating three sentences regarding topic in question and will appreciate it if you take time to check my attempts.

> Chest is to the left of the bed.
>   *Arca ad sinistram lectuli est.*
>
> Table is in the middle of the room.
>   *Mensa in medio mellae est.*
>
> There are colourful flowers in the crystal vase on the wooden table.
>   *Ibi flos colorati in vase crystallino super mensa lignea sunt.*

1. Is it correct to translate ***there are ...*** as *ibi ... sunt*? Maybe something less literal would be better?
2. Are there other mistakes? How to translate these sentences better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "there" in the English "there are" does not really refer to location.
It is often best to translate "there are" as simply *sunt*.
You should drop *ibi* from your sentence.
Also, the flower word *flos* should be in plural.
Otherwise the sentence looks good to me.

The second sentence is correct, apart from a small misprint: you probably meant *cellae* instead of *mellae*.
In *in medio cellae* the word *medium* is a noun, meaning "the center".

It is also possible to use the adjective *medius* and say *in media cella*.
It may sound like "in the central room", but it does also mean "in the center of the room".
Latin is like this; it is hard to distinguish the tallest mountain from the peak of a mountain (both can be *altissimus mons*).

I'm not sure about the first one — I don't know the idiomatic classical Latin way to put that in Latin.

Comment: Thank you! *mellae* is a typo indeed. Your answer leads to answer of [my another question](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/4978/why-in-medias-res-and-not-in-media-res) I think.

Comment: @PrzemysławP You are welcome! I just happened to finish typing a separate answer to the other question. :) I hope someone can comment on your first sentence in another answer; I'd much like to learn how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

As Joonas Ilmavirta stated, he is unsure of the correctness of the first example. This question interested me, so upon some digging through dictionary entries, I would like to posit that it would be a grammatically correct translation. [Lewis and Short](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=sinister&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059) provide this quote that led me to this conclusion:

> *aspice nunc ad sinistram*
>
> Look now to the left

This is a quote from Cicero's Philippics*, and it uses the noun *sinistra* to represent the left as a noun. This obviously comes from *sinister, -a, -um* the adjective, which bears a near identical meaning. I would like to make a special note about *ad* here, as it appears you just translated it from the English "to," as *ad* is most often used with "to." However, that is generally only with motion, not relative space. **But**, *ad* still works. Instead, interpret *ad* to mean "at" instead, and *sinistram* to mean "the left (-hand side)." This interpretation would make it seemingly a correct construction. I cannot attest to its definite use in classical literature, but it appears there is at least some proof that alludes to a similar, if not the same use.

---

*Upon further investigation, this appears to be an oddly manipulated quote. Two other texts I checked instead have:

> Aspicite *illam* a sinistra *equestrem statuam inauratam*

Not only has the command become plural, but the *nunc* has been dropped and the preposition is *a/ab* with the corresponding ablative. This suggests that the following is also an option:

> *Arca a sinistra lectuli est*
>
> The chest is by the left (-hand side) of the bed

If anyone could explain to me why the discrepancy in the quote exists, I would be very interested to find out more.